# How to use converted variable inside shell script

Tags: shell

I have below shell script:

```
while [[ -z "$hosts" ]];do
read hosts?"some string"
done
```

I want to convert this string to uppercase:

```
echo $hosts | awk '{print toupper(0)}'
```

Can I use this converted variable on some way? something like this:

```
bighosts="echo $hosts | awk '{print toupper(0)}'"

echo $bighosts
```

I know its not working, can you please provide me some way to use converted variable inside the script instead of creating new text file?

Comment: please update your posting and specify which shell. bash has built-in case conversions

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to convert a variable to upper case, one using `awk` and the other using `tr`:

```
host=abcd

# using awk
bighost=$(echo $host | awk '{print toupper($0)}')
echo host=$host bighost=$bighost
host=abcd bighost=ABCD

# using tr
bighost2=$(echo $host | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')
echo host=$host bighost2=$bighost2
host=abcd bighost2=ABCD
```

Comment: Why not show the bash built-in way?

Comment: Also, you have bugs here if you don't quote your parameter expansions. See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) and/or [BashPitfalls #14](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)

Comment: Also, note the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly including the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".